# How to expand/collapse Jstree node?

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, ui-automation, jstree

We are working on one automation activity to automate login and file download from external third party link. Our requirement is to use Powershell to perform this activity.

There are files kept under the different folder which all created using Jstree. so our code should go and expand the folder and find the specific file from the site. We could able to login and redirect to the specific page, But we stuck here in expanding the folders dynamically since we feel it little more complicated.

This is what we have tried so far.

```
$url = "http://testUrl.com"
$username = "User"
$password = "Password"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($url);

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;
}

$ie.Document.GetElementById("IDToken1").Value = $username
$ie.Document.GetElementByID("IDToken2").Value = $password
$ie.Document.GetElementById("Login.Submit").Click();

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;
}

$ie.Navigate($repoClearUrl);

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;
}

foreach ($element in $ie.Document.DocumentElement.GetElementsByClassName('jstree-node  jstree-closed jstree-last') | where {$_innerText -eq 'RDFBN'}) {
    if ($item.InnerText -eq 'RDFBN') {
        $item.Click()
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the client code and folder name

[image]

Comment: For one thing I believe `$item` is supposed to be `$element`.

Comment: Yeah,forgot to replace the element